# Mysql - "insert ... on duplicate key update" at concurrency

Tags: mysql, concurrency, sql-insert

I have a question about the function "insert  ... on duplicate key update".
is it safe at concurrent inserts?
I have the following situation:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE d=d+1;
```

where the following unique key exists (b,c)

if a lot of concurrent inserts of the query above are executed, is the value of the field "d" properly increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in InnoDB every concurrent insert will lock and increase your `d` value. First query will lock and insert row with default value for `d`